# How to compare strings typed in to strings in an array read fro a file?

Tags: java, arrays, string, text-files, token

I have written some code in java that is able to read a text file line by line then split the lines into words/tokens and store these in an array. I would like the program I am writing to allow me to input some text and compare this to the array of tokens stored. If there is a match, I would like the program to return the matching string and print it out as well as a few strings before and after the matching string. The piece of code I am working with is below. Kindly, let me know where I may have gone wrong and share any links or examples that may help me fix this problem. Many thanks.

```
//declare variables that will be involved in Find operation     
  String  equiptype;
  String  equipid;  
  String[] compareid;
  String[] comparetype; 

// Allow user to type in what they are looking for.
   System.out.println ("Enter the equipment type: ");
   equiptype = TextIO.getlnString(); 

   System.out.println("Enter the equipment id: ");
   equipid = TextIO.getlnString();

   //System.out.println("You searched for: " + equiptype + " " + "and" + " " + equipid); // testing the getlnString statements

  //comparing strings typed in to string array tokens to find a match 

  if (equiptype == null && equipid != null)
      compareid [0]= tokens[0];
      for(int j=0;j < tokens.length;j++){  
       compareid[k]=tokens[k];   
          if(!compareid.equals(equipid)) return false;
        else
              return compareid[j];

   System.out.println("Result: " + tokens[j-1] + " " + compareid [j] + " " + tokens [j+1] + " " + tokens[j+2] + " " + tokens[j+3]);
      }
  else if (equipid == null && equiptype != null)
  {
      comparetype [0]= tokens[0];

     for(int k=0;k < tokens.length;k++){ 
          if(!comparetype.equals(equiptype)) return false;
          comparetype = tokens[k];
          return comparetype[k];      

          System.out.println("Result: " + comparetype[k] + " " + tokens[k+1] + " " + tokens[k+2] + " " + tokens[k+3] + " " + tokens[k+4]);  
  }           

  else {
   System.out.println("Please Enter the equipment name and/or id  or click the 'List All' button.");
```

Comment: compareid [0]= tokens[0]; - where is tokens coming from?

Comment: this `comparetype [0]= tokens[0];` must be `comparetype [0].equals(tokens[0]);`, because this is a string type. Also the `compareid [0]= tokens[0];`

Comment: @Jens That isn't true depending on their Java version.

Comment: Define `FEW` (before and aft). Use the other input in the same way. `print(currentIndex - FEW, currrentIndex + FEW);`

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: @Jens and @ Scary Wombat: I have attempted to use your solution but I for some reason the tokens string array is not identified as being declared. I had declared the string array tokens in a try...catch when I was reading the text file and storing the split strings. I seem to be unable to use tokens outside the try...catch.

Comment: @Tanzanitemystiq57 declared it outside of the `try...catch`

Comment: @Jens I have declared it outside the try...catch but I still get the error "variable tokens might have not been initialized" when it is used outside the try...catch.

Comment: @Tanzanitemystiq57 Then initialize it with a empty array. If you can post the whole code, we can help you much better.

Comment: @Jens I will try to post the code in bits from the beginning...

Comment: Here is the code: package monitortest;

    import UsingJava.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Monitor {        
         
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException { 
                                
       String delims = "[-\n\r]";
       
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C:\info_sample.txt"); 
                        try {
                              Scanner input = new Scanner (file);....

Comment: ...while (input.hasNextLine()) {
     String inputfile = input.nextLine(); 
       String[] tokens = inputfile.split(delims);
                        }
                        }
                                                              
          catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
              System.err.format (" File not found.\n");
          }

Comment: The rest of the code is what was posted...

Comment: @Tanzanitemystiq57 Looks like the code is cutted. Can you edit the Question and post the code there?

Comment: Kindly note that I have reposted the question and code. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24529731/how-to-compare-strings-typed-in-by-user-to-strings-in-a-string-array-repost

Comment: There are a lot of compile errors in your code. I have added the declaration of tokens under the declarations of comparetype, and these error was gone. But there a a lot more error. 1) you can not use return if you are not in a function (and main is not a function in this case). There are severeal `}` missing at the end of `if`and `for`statement.

Comment: @Jens noted. I will out the errors with the missing brackets. I will attempt to re-declare the tokens string array as you suggested. Will the new string have the same strings stored in it as the previous tokens string array in the code?

Comment: Is there a way to make the stored string array tokens, available for the rest of the code to use?